# ul listener to onchange event doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a list of `input`

```
<ul id="list">
    <li><input type="text" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" /></li>
</ul>
```

Because there are many of them, I let `ul` do a event delegation:

```
function addHandler(element, type, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + type, handler);
    } else {
        element["on" + type] = handler;
    }
}
addHandler(document.getElementById("list"), "change", function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if (target.nodeName === "INPUT") {
        alert(target.value);
    }
});
```

This works well in Chrome, Firefox, but not in IE, what's the problem?
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/94ngc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `change` event is buggy in IE<9. Have a look at this chart:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html

As you can see, the change event works in all browsers, but IE only triggers it on the input element (I suppose it just doesn’t bubble correctly, or it is not available for other elements).

Try this as a test, it should work for the fist input in IE:

```
var inp = document.getElementById("list").firstChild.firstChild;
addHandler(inp, "change", function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if (target.nodeName === "INPUT") {
        alert(target.value);
    }
});
```

I suggest you loop through all your inputs and attach the listener to each element instead of delegating the event to the UL, or use an event normalizer like jQuery or YUI.

Note: your code seems to work fine in IE9+